# Are there two same md5sums in different files?

Tags: md5

Are there two files which has same md5sums but different content? Is there way to find such files easy-way?

is there some article/blog post about it ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, and they are relatively easy to find. It is called a hash collision. see [here](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/MD5#Collision_vulnerabilities) for more detail.